# Do PAAS solve scalability issue of BlazeDS?

Tags: java, apache-flex, blazeds, paas

We are developing a flash game with flex as client and java as server. For the communication between client and server we are planning to use BlazeDS. We are hoping that hundreds of thousands (maybe millions) of players will play the game concurrently but we find out that we would have problems on scaling because of the BlazeDS's limitations on the number of clients it can handle. We are not able to afford LCDS, and heard that GraniteDS does also have limitations (higher than BlazeDS but still not enough).

Would deploying our application to a PAAS such as Amazon Elastic Beanstalk solve this scaling problem considering the Blazeds's limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To summarize very quickly
With BlazeDS you have a limitation of a few hundreds connections per server.
With GraniteDS you have a limitation of a few thousands, possibly a few tens of thousands connections per server depending on your use case, size of payload, etc. (in fact the actual limits are those of the app server asynchronous I/O support, tomcat, jetty or whatever).
Using clustering (on a PaaS or wherever) would bring you to much higher numbers (not sure you can get to millions though).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you have any idea how does the scaling occur on the PAAS, considering which criteria?